# Are nested calls to `asyncio.gather()` dangerous?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

I wrote this ~100 line script recently, where I tried out Python's `asyncio` library. When it comes to asynchronous programming in Python, I just have 2 days of experience. I spent the last two days reading about it for the first time.

Based on all my readings and understanding, I think, there is no mess-up in the script, but there are some specific parts which I am a little skeptical about because of my inexperience in this area.

To be specific I am doing a `asyncio.gather(<unpacking a value here>, return_exceptions=True)`. This is the relevant function:

```
async def main():
districts = json.loads(os.environ['DISTRICTS'])
while True:
    start = perf_counter()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*(process_district(d, session) for d in districts), return_exceptions=True)
        for district, result in zip(districts, results):
            if isinstance(result, Exception):
                error = f"exception occurred when district {district['district_id']} was being processed: {result}"
                print(error)
                await send_telegram(os.environ['BOT_CHAT_ID'], error, session)
    print(f'time taken: {perf_counter() - start} seconds')
    sleep(int(os.environ['SLEEP_SECONDS']))
```

Now somewhere in the function call hierarchy of `process_district()`, there comes another `asyncio.gather()`, without `return_exceptions` flag. This is the relevant function:

```
async def send_notifications(chat_ids, cova_18_message, cova_45_message, covi_18_message, covi_45_message, session):
await asyncio.gather(
    send_telegram(chat_ids.get('cova_18'), cova_18_message, session),
    send_telegram(chat_ids.get('cova_45'), cova_45_message, session),
    send_telegram(chat_ids.get('covi_18'), covi_18_message, session),
    send_telegram(chat_ids.get('covi_45'), covi_45_message, session)
)
```

[My script](https://github.com/viiicky/covid/blob/master/vaccinate.py) is working all well as expected. However, I am a little bit uncertain if I am just doing anything wrong/bad here. To be specific, some of the worries that I have:

1. Is it fine where `asyncio.gather()` is "nested" in the hierarchy call. Can it have any bad implications?
2. My "inner" asyncio.gather() doesn't have `return_exceptions=True`. To be honest, this looks completely fine to me, but still, is there any catch / any code smell here? (I have also tested this, where the exceptions raised by the coroutines inside the inner `gather()` are also being awaited and iterated at the outer `gather()`)
3. Any other issue that is there with the way my script is written? Other than my inexperience, the only reason I am sceptical about this is, I was not able to find a single example on the wide Internet where people are calling `gather()` "inside" `gather()`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything inherently wrong or dangerous with nested `asyncio.gather` calls. However I think this question may be more suited to SO